# node, express, jade: How to process form data

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Is there any best practise code pattern how to process HTML form data with express and jade templates? I was wondering, if it would make sense to use a PHP like self calling loop of the form template, say in your router script you have two handler for the same route, one for GET and the other for POST requests. Something like:

```
exports.getHandler = function(req, res){
  res.render('/formhandling/', {mode: "form-filling"});
}

exports.postHandler = function(req, res){
  res.render('/formhandling/', {mode: "form-processing"});
}
```

and the jade template might look like

```
extends layout

block content

  h1 #{title}

  if mode == "form-processing"
    p Form data processed...

  else
    form(name="", method="post", action="/formhandling/")
    ...
```

Does that make any sense or did I get something completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you could just use jQuery to hide the form after the user submitted, instead of rendering the response again.  If you want to do any processing of the form on the server side, you can do that in your app.js.

```
app.get('/', routes.form);
app.post('/', function(res,req){
    /* form processing here
       you could also do this with an external route */
});
```

Edit: Also, [see my answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260946/using-emit-from-post/17263665#17263665)

Comment: Thnx for reply @iheartramen,

Comment: Thnx for reply @iheartramen,
I'm sure you're right. I realize that I really need to explore the philosohpy behind node.js much deeper. While thinking about your answer, more questions arrise such as:  How to pre-fill form elements, if submitted form data is partly wrong, but the correct parts should remain in the form...?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, that might not really even be a node.js question.  Check out this [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/05/sisyphus-js-client-side-drafts-and-more/).  I suggest validating your forms on the client-side as well, so that the user cannot submit the form in the first place unless it's valid, and you don't normally have the issue of pre-filling data they already entered again.  Also, see the edit to my answer above.