# Using .emit from POST

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, emit

Is there a way to emit to the current `socket` within a post method of *node.js* using *socket.io* and *express* without having to go through the `io.sockets.on('connection')`?

Here is my issue.  I am making a mini authorization system.  When the user submits from the form it post the data through `'/login'` instead of using a `onclick` emit.  If the user has an invalid user-name or password it should send a message back notifying it failed. I would prefer not to use the callback or write because I am using a *Jade* template.  You can see my source code [here](https://github.com/webbrandon/NodeAuth).

**Example:**
Server Side

```
var LoggIn = require('./lib/login.js'); // <-- Middle-ware
app.post('/login', function (req, res){
    LoggIn.authenticate(req.body.user, req.body.password, function(user, msg) {
        if (user) {
            req.session.user = user;
                res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            res.render('login');
            //res.emit('loginFail', 'You have entered an invalid user / password!<br>Try Again.); // <-- wishing for something like this
                console.log('Login Failed! : ' + msg);
        }
    });
});
```

**Example**
Client Side

JS

```
var status = document.getElementById('status');
socket.on('loginFail', function(msg) {
    status.innerHTML = msg;
});
```

Jade Form

```
#status
form#loginForm(method='POST', action='/login')
            input(name='user', placeholder='User Name')
            br
            input(name='password', placeholder='Password', type='password')
            br
            input(value='Sign In', type='submit')
```

Comment: Instead of using res.emit have you tried using the socket that was initialized on the server? Example: `socket.emit('loginFail','Can't log in');` Also I don't know if you can use sockets for this as the client would still need to connect after rendering the page, in which they would miss the emit. Is there a reason you can't do something like this `res.render('login',{error:'Invalid credentials'});` and then display the status if it exists

Comment: I never even thought to try and pass the data with the render method.  Jade and Node.js are still  pretty new to me so I really appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to do this without using io.sockets.on('connection') again.  If you're using res.render anyway, you could pass data through that though:

```
res.render('login', {msg: 'You have entered an invalid user / password!<br>Try Again.'});
```

and then do something like this in your jade doc to print out the message if it exists:

```
- if (msg)
     p #{msg}
```

But the problem with doing that is that it reloads the page, which I don't think you want if you're just trying to display a simple feedback message.  You could use jQuery to submit the form on the client side instead:

```
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(
            $(this).attr("action"), // The URL to send form data to
            $(this).serialize(), // Serializes the form data to be sent
            // Success callback function
            function(data){ 
                if(data.url){
                    window.location.href = data.url;
                } else{
                    $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

On the server-side you would have:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    // do whatever you need to check if the login is valid
    if(validLogin){
        res.send({url: myURL}); // send url that user should be redirected to
    } else{
        res.send({msg: 'You have entered an invalid user / password!<br>Try Again.'});
    }
});
```

So if the login is valid, the URL to redirect is sent back to the browser and the user is redirected.  If the login is not valid, the error message is sent back and is displayed.  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call) for more about submitting a form and then redirecting via jQuery.

Comment: Actually I think your first suggestion is a good one.  I am not minding a page reload with such little content and there is also some path configurations that rely on what I have done.  For my main pages I think you have a good point though.  Thank you for your feedback.