# How to re-render the page after a database add call without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

Hi I am using a form which takes input of some data and when I press submit an Ajax Post request goes to the server which then saves the data in the database and then data only gets updated on the ejs Page when I press refresh.
I want to know is there any way I can make any call through either Jquery or JavaScript that on the success of AJAX POST re renders the ejs page and page is again functional without refreshing?

I tried to use the below code to re load the page what it does is; it works, reloads the data but that data is not accessible or its values are not usable until I refresh

The code I used

```js
             $('body').load('views/test.ejs', function () {
              $(this).fadeIn(5000);
           });
```

My rendering function looks like this;

```
         function renderList(res, list) {
            res.render('admin', {
                jsonList: list, // JSON of data generated from DB
                listId:   req.session.user.listID, //global session
                access: req.session.user.Access, //global session
                products:   req.session.user.Products, //global session
                user:       req.session.user.FirstName || req.session.LastName 
            });
        }
```

I have a tabbable menu of bootstrap in which I am passing the IDs of the data from Databases and using those tabbable menu to display corresponding data of that item. So I am not getting IDs when I just use the Load function. only `location.reload()` works for me but its not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) have success callback functions that you can use to update the page with your new data.  Try looking at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260946/using-emit-from-post/17263665#17263665) for an example.

Comment: Yes you are close to what I want to achieve, as when I submit data through Ajax post I use Success call back for displaying success message, in their I want to implement something that on Success of this ajax request, When i close the Modal page gets updated by itself. But jquery.Load does that, but it just doesn't do what refreshing the page do, it just renders the empty shell with data, I can't use that data for other purposes

Comment: Let me make sure I"m getting what you're saying:  The form is in a modal.  On success of the AJAX post, the page updates with the data that was added to the database.  But you can't use the data for anything besides displaying it?  What other purposes are you not able to use the data for?

Comment: Bingo you are right on Target, I have a tabbable menu of bootstrap in which I am passing the IDs of the data from Databases and using those tabbable menu to display corresponding data of that item. So I am not getting IDs when I just use the Load function. only `location.reload()` works for me but its not a good way to do it.